# How do I do a minimized chi-square for signal processing?

Tags: python, python-3.x, scipy, scipy-optimize-minimize

I am trying to wrap my head around the syntax for `scipy.optimize.minimize`. I have read the docs again and again and googled but I simply don't understand how to do this. Hope someone can point me in the right direction:

I have a signal (`numpy array`) that I wish to match with a template signal (same-length numpy array) in such a way, that I determine which signal baseline adjustment and amplitude multiplication factor would result in the lowest chi-square. I think I need to do something along the lines of minimizing

(baselineadjust + amplitudefactor * templatearray - signalarray)**2

I would like to use baselineadjust and amplitudefactor to subsequently modify the signal, subtracting the modified template, i.e.

newsignal = baselineadjust + amplitudefactor * templatearray - signalarray

The purpose of this maneuver is to effectively remove the template signal from the actual signal, leaving the remaining signal/noise.

Not sure if this makes sense and happy to elaborate.

```
#data is a (very) long list of floats, that contains a noisy signal and a repetitive signal of a specific length but with slight variations in amplitude, partially due to the noisy signal and partially because it inherently varies a bit. I wish to remove the repetitive signal from the data.

#Prior to this, I detect signals in data:
sigwindows = []

#Gather signals
for sig in signals:
    sigwindow = list(data[sig-200:sig+200])
    sigwindows += [sigwindow]

#Construct an averaged signal
avgsig = np.mean(sigwindows, axis=0)

for sig in signals:
    sigwindow = list(data[sig-200:sig+200])

    #First, I subtract the average signal
    data[sig-200:sig+200] = list(np.array(sigavg) - np.array(sigwindow))

    #This removes some of the signal, but due to the inherent variation in amplitude, some of it remains.
    #Instead would like to do this:

    data[sig-200:sig+200] = list(np.array(sigavg) - baselineadjust - amplitudefactor * np.array(sigwindow))

    #... having obtained 'baselineadjust' and 'amplitudefactor' as described above, by minimizing chi-square.
```

Comment: Post the code you are currently running.

Comment: Cheers, added some code – but as described above I do not understand how to use scipy.optimization.minimize (if this is what I need) to do this.